# Place the collection view cells vertically instead of horizontally?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

How to design UICollectionView in such a way that it fills the collection view cells vertically (column-wise) instead of filling horizontally (row-wise)?

The collection view should be vertically scrollable, I should not change the size of the collection cell and determine the number of rows dynamically?

Comment: make the width of the cells the same width of the collectionview

Comment: Set the flow layout scroll direction to `horizontal`.

Comment: It's working but I should be able to limit the number of rows too, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I use this code for it:

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

For limited number of rows you can set collectionView height and set height of cell and spacings. For example, if you need 2 cells in column, you will write:

```
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.size.width / 5, height: self.collectionView.frame.size.height / 2.5)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
```

you can change this parameters like you need

Comment: This really helps me, but the collection view should be vertically scrollable and the number of rows is to be determined dynamically in such a way that I should not scroll horizontally.

Comment: oh, wow. CollectionView is default object with it propertys. I don't no, but you can calculate how many cells show in one row, and according this calculate how many rows you need.

Comment: and do it programmatically, place CollectionView inside scrollView, for example, and set CollectionView.isScrollEnabled = false

Comment: I can do that but the since the scroll direction is horizontal, the cells are horizontally scrollable.

Answer (score -1):

```
(YOUR_COLLECTIONVIEW_NAME.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout).scrollDirection = .horizontal
```

Comment: Please add an explanation on what this code does and how/why it solves OP's problem.